# source.uri should not be an empty string

Tags: react-native

please solve this problem . it had been 4 days of of this error
 and the  developer can understand its pain. i also log in the console but it was fine . but in render it is not working.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    term: '',
    imgLink: '',
  };
};

fetchData = data => {
   var foo = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
  this.setState({imgLink: foo});
}

render (){
  return(
  <Image 
    style={{
      width:width,
      height:70,
      alignItems:'center',
      borderRadius:50,
      marginLeft:'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
      marginTop: 100
    }} 
    source={this.props.url ? { uri: this.props.imgLink } : null}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used props instead of state in url access. As you can see you declared variable imgLink in state not as props.

this.state = {
    term: '',
    imgLink: '',
  };

Solution:
source={this.state.imgLink ? { uri: this.state.imgLink } : null}/>

use above instead of props.